# Can I use forecasted value to update neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast the daily production of a well using a neural network trained on data from other wells, where the daily production of the previous day is one of the parameters. Since the geographical properties differ from well to well, my strategy is:

1. updating the network based on the data of the target well from the initial production period (say 50 days)
2. forecasting the production after this period day by day

I'm wondering in step 2, whether it is feasible to update the network using forecasted daily production. If it is feasible, should I update the network everyday or every a period of time? Also, how should I decide the number epochs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to hear more about the specific features you are using to say for sure. Sounds like you could do this, but you want to be careful, because the errors/uncertainty will likely compound the further you try to forecast into the future. In general, the act of using forecasted values in your training data is called [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning), so that's something to look into.

But I think for your problem you may be better off looking into models specifically designed for time series forecasting, like [RNNs and LSTMs](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/neural-networks-for-forecasting-financial-and-economic-time-series-6aca370ff412).

Hope that helps some!